# Full Text Search FTS4 error - unable to use function MATCH

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, android-room

I am trying to implement FTS4 in my app which also uses Room. It's not a very complicated set-up based on the documentation and tutorials I have read but I have a persistent error triggered by my query which I can't seem to figure out.

My fts table is being created and populated correctly as I can see in the db inspector. Also, I can run queries on it and with no problems until I try to run any query with MATCH. I get the following

```
Error retrieving data from table.: unable to use function MATCH in the requested context (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)
```

For instance, this works (although it doesn't make sense to use):

```
SELECT * FROM community_features JOIN features_fts ON community_features.rowid = features_fts.rowid WHERE features_fts.feature_name LIKE '%TEST%'
```

But this doesn't:

```
SELECT * FROM community_features JOIN features_fts ON community_features.rowid = features_fts.rowid WHERE features_fts.feature_name MATCH '*TEST*'
```

UPDATE - Comparing my app to another, I noticed that their FTS is generating several more files than mine. In my database inspector I can see the completed features_fts table but I don't see the _docsize, _segdir, _segments or _stat tables that appear in the other app. I'm guessing these should be autogenerated somehow and that's why my MATCH function won't work. Did I miss a step in the process?

Below are my files:

DB set-up

```
    public class FeatureIndexDBClient {

    private final FeatureIndexDB mDb;
    private static String mDbName;
    private static FeatureIndexDBClient mInstance;

    private FeatureIndexDBClient(Context context, String dbName) {
        if(mDbName == null || !mDbName.equalsIgnoreCase(dbName)) {
            mDbName = dbName;
        }
        mDb = Room.databaseBuilder(context, FeatureIndexDB.class, dbName)
                .addCallback(new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                        super.onCreate(db);
                        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO features_fts(feature_name) VALUES ('rebuild')");
                    }
                })
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();
    }

    public static synchronized FeatureIndexDBClient getInstance(Context context, String dbName) {
        if (mInstance == null || mDbName == null || !mDbName.equalsIgnoreCase(dbName)) {
            mInstance = new FeatureIndexDBClient(context, dbName);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public FeatureIndexDB getAppDatabase() {
        return mDb;
    }

    public void close() {
        this.mDb.close();
    }

    public SimpleSQLiteQuery getFeatureFTSQuery() {
        return new SimpleSQLiteQuery("INSERT INTO features_fts(feature_name) SELECT community_features.feature_name FROM community_features");
    }
}
```

Entities:

```
@Entity(tableName = "community_features")
public class OSCommunityFeature implements Parcelable {

    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rowid")
    private Long rowId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    private String _id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "community_id")
    private int communityId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "feature_id")
    private int featureId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "feature_type")
    private Integer featureType;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "feature_name")
    private String feature_name;

    public OSCommunityFeature() {

    }

    ... constructors, getters, setters
}



@Entity(tableName = "features_fts")
@Fts4(contentEntity = OSCommunityFeature.class)
public class CommunityFeatureFTS {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "rowid")
    private Long rowId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "feature_name")
    private String feature_name;

    public CommunityFeatureFTS() {
    }

    public CommunityFeatureFTS(Long id, String name) {
        this.rowId = id;
        this.feature_name = name;
    }
```

The table is populated by after retrieving data from the server. Once the data is loaded into the db I then call:

```
"INSERT INTO features_fts(feature_name) SELECT community_features.feature_name FROM community_features"
```

My dao is as follows:

```
@Dao
public interface FeatureIndexDAO {

// Community Features --------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertAllFeatures(List<OSCommunityFeature> features);

@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM community_features")
List<OSCommunityFeature> getAllFeatures();

@RawQuery
boolean setFeatureFTSTable(SupportSQLiteQuery query);

@Query("SELECT * FROM community_features JOIN features_fts ON community_features.rowid = features_fts.rowid WHERE features_fts.feature_name MATCH :searchFor")
List<OSCommunityFeature> searchForFeatures(String searchFor);
```

Gradle:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6"
annotationProcessor  'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.2.6'
```

I have been reading everything I can find but have been using [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/14292824-full-text-search-in-room-tutorial-getting-started) and [this](https://medium.com/@sienatime/enabling-sqlite-fts-in-room-2-1-75e17d0f0ff8). I can download the example project from the first link, build it, and run it with no problems. I really can't tell what the difference could be. I've been going back and forth for about a day now.

Anybody have any hints or clues that might point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after way too much time...

I needed to change

```
annotationProcessor  'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.2.6'
```

to:

```
annotationProcessor  'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.6'
```

‍♂️